# Is there something like 'initialize' in J?

Tags: j

In python, we can write 'initialize' to let all algorithm proceed automatically after the user inputs his or her choice. I was wondering how to accomplish such thing in J.

```
def __init__(self, a = xxx, b = xxxx, c = xx, d = x):
             self.a = 'a'
             self.d = `d`
             self.b = 'b' 
             self.c = 'c'
              )
```

Comment: You can create optional left arguments using [explicit `:`](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/d310n.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, I am not aware of anything beyond setting global values at the top of a script.

```
variable=: value   NB. =: is essential to create a value that exists outside of the script
```

In J you can re-assign everything to verbs, nouns, conjunctions or adverbs. You control those assignments, so if you don't want it to change, don't re-assign it. You can use locales to create namespaces that are less likely to be changed accidentally if that is your concern.

```
variable_locale_ =: value NB. locale name is the character string that separates _'s
```

But you can still re-assign values in that locale, it is just less likely that a user is going to do it accidentally.

Perhaps someone who knows Python better will give a more accurate answer.